# Watching videos during CUDA computation on NVIDIA graphic card

Tags: graphics-card, video, gpu, cuda

I currently spent much of my PC time to compute Neural Nets using CUDA and my NVIDIA GTX 980 graphic cards. While CUDA works I have some kind of FPS drop and little freezes on my monitor. It actually OK while you serfing the web. But it make Youtube videos to lost some frames (and strange reordering of frames). Also I can't run videos in Media Player, since they lost many frames too. It's looks like watch some HD movie on outdated computer.

I tried to disable GPU support in MPC. Tried to install VLC. But it didn't work. It looks like the problem not with absence of computational power, but with render picture on monitor (which made by GPU).

Anyone had this problem before? Or have any solution for this?

Comment: have you checked your media player for buffer settings? increase the buffer size if possible.

Comment: It didn't help. I increased it to 1024 MB without success. ( Looks like the problem is with GPU frame buffer.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Most browsers supported being hardware accelerated, and depending on the video quality, your browser must use your GPU to display the video.  You should provide more information with regards to your VLC installation problem.